# What Type can I pass to a Where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to store an expression in a variable and then pass that to a Where clause in a linq statement, but I can't seem to figure out what `Type` I need to use.  The result I would like to achieve is:

```
var expression = x => x.UserId == 5;

var result = db.Table.Where(expression);
```

I know the `Type` of the entities stored in `Table` is required somewhere, but no idea where.

Comment: Clue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DavidG: Not quite. The OP is likely after [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which takes `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`), not [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which takes `Func<TSource, bool>`).

Comment: @Douglas Well that's why I said it was a clue, not a complete answer!

Comment: It's a misleading clue... `Func<Foo, bool> f = x => x.UserId == 5;` would also compile, but it wouldn't give the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expression = x => x.UserId == 5;
```

(replace `Foo` with the actual type of the entities in `Table` of course...)

Comment: @Tevis, there is actually nothing hard about it; `Func<Foo, bool>` is a function that takes a `Foo` and returns a `bool` (IOW, a "predicate"). `Expression<X>`, where X is a delegate type, represents the abstract syntax tree for a delegate of type X.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Isn't this answer correct? Isn't it helping the OP? Just because it's an answer to a basic question doesn't make it a bad answer...

Comment: So `Expression<X>` represents the `x => x` syntax?

Comment: @Tevis, `Expression<X>` is a representation of the lambda's code; this representation can be examined, analyzed, transformed into something else (e.g. SQL in the case of Entlty Framework or Linq2SQL), etc.